# Force update screen, reboot server and refresh with Javascript

Tags: javascript, screen, flush, reboot

I'm trying to do a web server based application. I'm working on the internal configuration of the server and I want it to be able to be modified by the user. I'm using a raspberry pi 3 as web server.

Right now I'm trying to configure the Static IP, for this I have modified the dhcpc.conf file with php code. After that I want to reboot the raspberry so it takes the new configuration. I am already able to do that, but when I force the reboot, the server doesn't send the information to the web browser and I am getting page not found.

What I want to know is how to force the server to update the web page before the shutdown, and then how (using javascript may be) reload the page after XX seconds (when the raspberry is booted again).

This is my code until now:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>Configuración: Red</title>
    <link href="/TrafficVC/ccs/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/configuraRed.js"></script>

    <style>

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 class="pagesTitle">Configuración: Red</h1>

    <form action="" method="post" name="chNetConf">
        <table class="tbChNetConf" id="chNetConfTable">
            <tr>
                    <td class="izq">Hostname:</td>
                    <td class="der"> <input type="text" name="Hostname" <?php echo "value=".gethostname();?>> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="izq" style="font-weight:bold">Conexión Ethernet: </td>
                <td class="der">

                    <label>
                        <span>IP Estática</span>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="chbEthStaticEnable" name="chbEthStaticEnable" onchange="enableEthStatic(this)">
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td class="izq" style="font-weight:bold">Conexión Wireless: </td>
                <td class="der">
                    <label>
                        <span>Habilitar</span>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="chbWlanEnable" name="chbWlanEnable" onchange="enableWlan(this)">
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <span>IP Estática</span>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="chbWlanStaticEnable" name="chbWlanStaticEnable" onchange="enableWlanStatic(this)" disabled>
                    </label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="vertical-align:top">
                    <table class="tbChNetConf">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="izq">IP:</td>
                            <td class="der">
                                <input type="text" id="EthIP1" name="EthIP1" disabled style="width:15%">
                                .
                                <input type="text" id="EthIP2" name="EthIP2" disabled style="width:15%">
                                .
                                <input type="text" id="EthIP3" name="EthIP3" disabled style="width:15%">
                                .
                                <input type="text" id="EthIP4" name="EthIP4" disabled style="width:15%">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="izq">Mascara:</td>
                            <td class="der">
                                <input type="text" id="EthMask1" name="EthMask1" disabled style="width:15%">
                                .
                                <input type="text" id="EthMask2" name="EthMask2" disabled style="width:15%">
                                .
                                <input type="text" id="EthMask3" name="EthMask3" disabled style="width:15%">
                                .
                                <input type="text" id="EthMask4" name="EthMask4" disabled style="width:15%">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="izq">Puerta de enlace:</td>
                            <td class="der"> 
                                <input type="text" id="EthGate1" name="EthGate1" disabled style="width:15%">
                                .
                                <input type="text" id="EthGate2" name="EthGate2" disabled style="width:15%">
                                .
                                <input type="text" id="EthGate3" name="EthGate3" disabled style="width:15%">
                                .
                                <input type="text" id="EthGate4" name="EthGate4" disabled style="width:15%">                                    
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2";>
                    <table class="tbChNetConf">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="izq">SSID:</td>
                            <td class="der"> 
                                <input type="text" id="WlanSSID" name="WlanSSID" disabled style="width:80%"> 
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="izq">Contraseña:</td>
                            <td class="der"> 
                                <input type="password" id="WlanPass" name="WlanPass" disabled> 
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td class="izq">IP:</td>
                            <td class="der" > 
                                <input type="text" id="WlanIP1" name="WlanIP1" disabled style="width:15%">
                                .
                                <input type="text" id="WlanIP2" name="WlanIP2" disabled style="width:15%">
                                .
                                <input type="text" id="WlanIP3" name="WlanIP3" disabled style="width:15%">
                                .
                                <input type="text" id="WlanIP4" name="WlanIP4" disabled style="width:15%">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="izq">Mascara:</td>
                            <td class="der" style="table-layout: fixed; width=100%"> 
                                <input type="text" id="WlanMask1" name="WlanMask1" disabled style="width:15%"> 
                                .
                                <input type="text" id="WlanMask2" name="WlanMask2" disabled style="width:15%"> 
                                .
                                <input type="text" id="WlanMask3" name="WlanMask3" disabled style="width:15%"> 
                                .
                                <input type="text" id="WlanMask4" name="WlanMask4" disabled style="width:15%"> 
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="izq">Puerta de enlaceqe:</td>
                            <td class="der"> 
                                <input type="text" id="WlanGate1" name="WlanGate1" disabled style="width:15%">  
                                .
                                <input type="text" id="WlanGate2" name="WlanGate2" disabled style="width:15%">  
                                .
                                <input type="text" id="WlanGate3" name="WlanGate3" disabled style="width:15%">  
                                .
                                <input type="text" id="WlanGate4" name="WlanGate4" disabled style="width:15%">  
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" style="text-align:center;"> 
                    <input type="submit" value="Guardar" name="submitChNet">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

    <?php
        if (isset($_GET['Err']))
        {
            echo "Error " . $_GET['Err']. ": ";
            if ($_GET['Err']=="EthIP")
                echo "La dirección IP de la conexión ethernet no es correcta";
            if ($_GET['Err']=="EthMask")
                echo "La máscara de la conexión ethernet no es correcta";
            if ($_GET['Err']=="EthGate")
                echo "La puerta de enlace de la conexión ethernet no es correcta";
        }
    ?>

</body>
</html>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitChNet']))
{
    include('phpCode/chNetConf.php');
}
?>
```

The file phpCode/chNetConf.php after writing the new file calls another shutdown.php file:

```
<?php
    echo exec('sudo reboot',$output);
?>
```

I hope I'm clear enough and you can help me.

By the way, there is no need of security. Also, I know this can be done because I took the idea on how my router can be configured.